# How to use socket.io to emit some data from controller rather than the the file in which connection established

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In my nodejs server i had connected socket.io and mongodb and the fronted is in rectjs . I had connected the socket.io and emitting or listening for changes but i want to listen for every new user added on the database and then emit to all about that happen .I had made the API in which user signin and I want whenever new user signin the in that controller the socket.io should listen and then emit about the user.

i had connected socket.io in app.js and the listening logic in userController.js

Here is my socket connection in app.js

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(`connected ${socket.id}`);
  //creating user as soon as new client connected

  //sending all user but not working
  User.find()
    .then(result => {
      socket.emit("Users", result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  //sending the same id which connected now
  socket.emit("YOUR_ID", socket.id);


  socket.on("disconnection", () => {
    console.log(`disconnected ${socket.id}`);
  });
});
```

here is my userController.js

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        })
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);

            if (!user) {
                console.log('no user');

                return res.json({
                    msg: 'no user'
                })
            } else {
                //here i want to listen 
                return res.json({

                    msg: 'User exists'
                });

            }
        })
}
```

I just want to listen for the new user sign and then emit but the problem is I cannot do that logic.

If I need to add socket.io as express middle-ware or anything than also fine.

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const socketConnection=io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(`connected ${socket.id}`);
  //creating user as soon as new client connected

  //sending all user but not working
  User.find()
    .then(result => {
      socket.emit("Users", result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  //sending the same id which connected now
  socket.emit("YOUR_ID", socket.id);


  socket.on("disconnection", () => {
    console.log(`disconnected ${socket.id}`);
  });
});
```

and then set that varibale with express

```
express.set('socketConnection',socketConnection);
```

and the get that and use that

const connection= app.get('socketConnection')